# Spring JDBC reading from tables

Tags: java, spring, maven, jdbc

These are code using to add data to Database using JDBC how can i retrieve data from same  table?? using JDBC am using project language level 8 at 1.7 jdk with spring 4 and maven

```
public void MysqlCall() throws Exception {
        SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(masterJdbcTemplate).withTableName("user")
                .usingColumns("name","status");
        Map<String, Object> testInsertMap = Maps.newHashMap();

        testInsertMap.put("status", "0");
        testInsertMap.put("name", "gopu");
        try {
            simpleJdbcInsert.execute(testInsertMap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: were yo able to resolve this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `masterJdbcTemplate` is a `DataSource`, you can simply create a `JdbcTemplate` from that. If it's already a `JdbcTemplate` - you're all set.

```
JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(masterJdbcTemplate);
```

Use this to simply query data:

```
List<String> names = jdbc.queryForList(
     //SQL Query
     "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM user WHERE status = 0", 
     //Type of values to return
     String.class);
```

Check out [JavaDoc of JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) and Stack Overflow of cause ;-) for more query options with JdbcTemplate.